# R - how to make color ramp colors more different

Tags: r, plot, colors

I am using color as a 3rd dimension in the example below.

```
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol = 2), width = c(5,1),height = c(1,1))
#rgPal = colorRampPalette(c('red','green')) 
col.jet = function(x, alpha=1) {rev(rainbow(x,start=5/6,end=4/6,alpha=alpha))}
rstc = rstc[order(rstc$efet),]
#rstc$cor = rgPal(nrow(rstc))[as.numeric(cut(rstc$efet,breaks = nrow(rstc)))]
rstc$cor = col.jet(100)[seq(1,85,12)]
par(mai = c(1,1,.3,.6)) 
plot(rstc$sens,rstc$prec, pch=15,col=rstc$cor)
text(rstc$sens-.001,rstc$prec, rstc$cp,cex=.5)
par(mai = c(1,0,.3,0))
legend_image = as.raster(matrix(rstc$cor[order(rstc$cor, decreasing = T )] , ncol=1))
plot(c(0,1),c(0,1),type = 'n', axes = F, xlab = '', ylab = '')
text(x=0.2, y =(1:8)/8, labels = rstc$efet, cex = .5)
rasterImage(legend_image,  xleft=0.3, ybottom=0, xright=.6, ytop=1)
```

**Data**

```
> rstc
      cp        qx   efet  prec  sens   acu    p_pred       cor
8 0.0100 0.2785192  5.772 0.340 0.223 0.664 0.6559006 #0000FFFF
1 0.0020 0.2075472  7.838 0.337 0.337 0.632 0.9997516 #009BFFFF
7 0.0080 0.2901235 10.586 0.346 0.342 0.638 0.9874534 #00FFC9FF
6 0.0075 0.2915392 11.536 0.349 0.345 0.640 0.9877019 #00FF2EFF
2 0.0030 0.2084507 11.961 0.350 0.349 0.640 0.9967702 #6CFF00FF
5 0.0060 0.2905473 12.437 0.352 0.347 0.642 0.9839752 #FFF700FF
4 0.0050 0.2777778 12.957 0.353 0.353 0.641 0.9997516 #FF5D00FF
3 0.0040 0.2504440 13.201 0.354 0.351 0.642 0.9940373 #FF003EFF
```

But the colors, mainly in upper scale, are too much alike.
Trying to make the colors more different, according to @jgadoury suggestion, I modified it to use jet color scale. It would be a better solution, but for some reason, colors don´t match values! For example, `cp=0.004` should be the top color, yellow in the scale, but it is red!
Did I make a mistake?
[see plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWQTD.png)

Comment: Look into `?colorRamp`. Additional custom palettes exist I believe in other packages.

Comment: You could add more colors to your color ramp: `rgPal = colorRampPalette(c('red','blue','green')) `

Comment: I would use ggplot2. It makes this type of figure so much easier. Also check your red-green scale is colourblind friendly

Comment: As @RichardTelford said, red-green color schemes are specifically not colorblind friendly. (It is the most common color vision deficiency; ~10% of white males can't tell the difference between the two)

Comment: If you want a jet color scale, you use the following function `col.jet <- function(x, alpha=1) {rev(rainbow(x,start=5/6,end=4/6,alpha=alpha))}` and then in your `plot` call you could set `col=col.jet(100)`

Comment: I´d tried 'red-blue', 'blue-green' and 3 colors scales with similar results. 'red-green' would be more meaningful, meaning no-go(red), go(green). Is there a ggplot example anywhere? Tks! @RichardTelford (I can´t cite shayaa here).

Comment: Take a look at RColorBrewer package, very simple and straight forward to use.  It has several very distinct color palettes.  (http://www.colorbrewer.org)